# unite two strings by copying one by one the characters of the second at the end of the first

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

this program it suppose to print Hello World but guess what exited, segmentation fault why is that happening ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char f(char *a, char *b) 
{
    int i , m, n;
    m = strlen(a);
    n = strlen(b);
    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        a[m+i] = b[i];
    }
}

int main() {
char*str1 = "hello ";
char*str2 = "world!";
str1=f(str1, str2);
printf("%s", str1);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to modify string literals. Use arrays with enough elements instead for strings to be modified.

Also assigning the return value of `f` to `str1` is a bad idea because no `return` statement is executed in the function `f` and using its return value invokes *undefined behavior*. The return type should be changed to `void` if you are not going to return anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(char *a, char *b) 
{
    int i , m, n;
    m = strlen(a);
    n = strlen(b);
    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        a[m+i] = b[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    char str1[16] = "hello ";
    char*str2 = "world!";
    f(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that you copy characters one by one?
Because if it's not you can just copy one string to another like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char str1[] = "hello ";
  char str2[] = "world!";
  char *result = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1); 
  strcpy(result, str1);
  strcat(result, str2);
  printf("%s", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will cause out-of-range access (*undefined behavior*) because `str1` only has elements for `"hello "`.

Comment: Does `str1` has enough memory to store `str2`

Comment: Yeah... right, how about this edited solution then?

Comment: Wrong because `str3` doesn't have space for terminating null-character and its value is used without initialization.

Comment: Okay, so what if I use strcpy at the first and add closing at the end? :D

Comment: Your code is still wrong. `strcpy()` and `strcat()` will do null-termination and your `str3[l+1] = '\0';` is out-of-range access.

Comment: Now it looks OK other than the result of `malloc()` is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this:

```
char*str1 = "hello ";
```

is a pointer to constant data, which means that you can't change the string `"hello "`

This is a constant pointer to variable data:

```
char str1[] = "hello ";
```

Which means that `str1` always points to the same address in memory, but you can modify the content of that chunk of memory.

However `str1` will have a fixed size of 7 characters (don't forget to count `\0`), so you can't append another string to it.

You could define a size `#define SIZE 20` large enough to store both strings and declare

```
char str1[SIZE] = "hello ";
```

Or you could declare `str1` as a VLA (variable length array) after having declared the string to append:

```
char*str2 = "world!";
char str1[strlen("hello ")+strlen(str2)+1] = "hello ";
```

Where the `+1` is for `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you may not change string literals (in this case the string literal pointed to by the pointer `str1`).

```
char*str1 = "hello ";
char*str2 = "world!";
```

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate a character array large enough to store the result string with the appended string literal pointed to by the pointer `str2`.

Secondly there is already the standard C function `strcat` that performs the required task.  If you have to write such a function yourself then it seems you should not use any string function as for example `strlen`.

And the return type char of your function does not make a sense. And moreover actually your function returns nothing.

So this assignment

```
str1=f(str1, str2);
```

results in undefined behavior.

The function and the program in whole can be written the following way without using standard string functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * f( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;
    
    while ( *p ) ++p;
    
    while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );
    
    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[14] = "Hello ";
    char *s2 = "World!";
    
    puts( f( s1, s2 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

Pay attention to that the second function parameter shall have the qualifier `const` because the pointed string is not changed within the function. And the function return type should be `char *` that is the function should return the result string.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not allowed to change a constant string, that is undefined behaviour.

Secondly your `f` function has no return statement and thus returns random data, making the `str1` variable in `main` point to random memory. Using it then also has undefined behaviour.

To fix it you should allocate new memory and concatenate the string into that

```
char* f(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) +1);
    if (s) {
        strcpy(s, s1);
        strcat(s, s2);
    }
    return s;
}
```

The extra one byte allocated is for the terminating zero.

Both arguments are `const` as there is no reason to modify them, which allows both arguments to be literal strings.